# Accessing the Local server from iOS over Wifi

Tags: ios, dns, router

My development environment is:
I have a Server application running on the windows and modified host.dat file to map to IP address with server url something like that

```
192.168.1.220 server.dev.com  
192.168.1.221 server-rc.dev.com
```

to access these servers from Mac application I had to modify mac host file and it seems to be running fine till now.

Now I need to access the local server from iPhone, all the machines are in same wifi, is there any way to access the server application which is running over the window in my private network,

Googling the same problem, it says I need to setup the DNS name in the router, but I am not getting how to do the same.

**Update:**
From the iPhone simulator I am able to access server, problem coming only form the device.

Comment: Why don't you use directly the IP instead of the server names when using the iPhone?

Comment: @apascua, this is i am going to make it last option, some changes also has to be done on the server code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for looking at it,

Making use of Fiddler, I could resolve this issue.

Detailed example [here](http://conceptdev.blogspot.com/2009/01/monitoring-iphone-web-traffic-with.html)